# Databricks ETL -> BigQuery, WRITE_TRUNCATE not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, etl

I'm running an ETL on Databricks, writing to BigQuery. I'm trying to get the code to "WRITE_TRUNCATE", aka write over the data every time it runs. This involves changing the BigQuery Configuration.

I've tried a bunch of things, but haven't gotten it to work. Here is my current code snippet:

```
import com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryConfiguration
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set(BigQueryConfiguration.OUTPUT_TABLE_WRITE_DISPOSITION_KEY, "WRITE_TRUNCATE")
```

This sends the error:

```
"error: value OUTPUT_TABLE_WRITE_DISPOSITION_KEY is not a member of object com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryConfiguration"
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/43)? Specifically: `conf.set("mapreduce.job.outputformat.class",classOf[IndirectBigQueryOutputFormat[,]].getName)`

Comment: Yes I've looked at that and tried a bunch of variations, everything threw an error except one, and that one still duplicated the data when I ran it

Answer (score 0):

Try following block of code to set the configurations:

```
    import com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.output.BigQueryOutputConfiguration;
    import com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFileFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
    import com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.output.IndirectBigQueryOutputFormat;

    BigQueryOutputConfiguration.configure(conf ,projectId ,outputDatasetId ,outputTableId,outputSchema ,Temp_Gcs_path ,BigQueryFileFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON ,classOf[TextOutputFormat[_,_]])
    ...
    conf.set("mapreduce.job.outputformat.class",classOf[IndirectBigQueryOutputFormat[,]].getName)
```

It will be easier to understand the problem if you could provide more details of the question, i.e., what you are trying to achieve, complete pseudo code of your use case etc.